# How to clear initial values on SelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in a form within an `UpdateView`.

I want to display the standard `SelectMultiple` widget but to clear all the initial `selected` attributes on the instance option values. By default `SelectMultiple` will select all the existing values; I want to clear this.

I thought I could do this via the widget attrs but I am mistaken since the following does not remove the `selected` attr from `<option value="" selected>`:

```
    form.fields['people'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='email',
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'selected': None})
    )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* Have you tried?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, yes hence the code and question.